# ¿Como puedo redimensionar una gran cantidad de imagenes sin que se desborde la memoria?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Re-dimensiono unas imágenes con javascript en Node js mi problema se encuentra a la hora de re-dimensionar muchas imágenes(en mi caso son unas 5500), la memoria se desborda. Lo que entiendo que sucede es que carga primero todas las imagenes en memoria y luego las redimensiona y las escribe. estoy usando el modulo amazing-image-resizer. Quisiera que a medida que leo la imagen, redimensione y la escriba para así liberar memoria, de forma secuencial o sino alguna solucion con la que pueda administrar tantas imagenes. Debajo dejo el modulo y el codigo donde llamo al modulo

```
function cambiarTamanio(ruta,tam){
    return new Promise( async(resolver,rechazar)=>{
        console.log("Cambiando el tamaño de: "+ruta);
        //console.log("a un tamaño de: "+tam+"X"+tam+" pixeles. Espere "+segundosCambioTamanio+" segundos.");
        
        try {
            await resizer(ruta,tam);
        } catch (error) {
            rechazar("Detalle: Error modificando los archivos.");
        }

        setTimeout(()=>{
            //da un tiempo a que realice la modificacion de tamaños
            resolver("Tamaño modificado!!");
        },segundosCambioTamanio *1000)
    });
}
```

```
module.exports = (folderPath, customWidth) => {
  if (!folderPath || !customWidth) {
    console.log(
      chalk.redBright("please provide valid input. We need valid folder path and custom width.")
    );
  }

  const dist = path.join(folderPath, "dist");

  // make sure there's a dist folder
  if (!fs.existsSync(dist)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(dist, { recursive: true });
  }

  fs.readdir(folderPath, function (err, files) {
    if (err) {
      alert("error reading orig folder");
    }

    files.forEach(async (file) => {
      const imageName = file;
      const width = customWidth;

      const imagePath = path.join(folderPath, imageName);
      const height = width * dimension(imagePath);

      console.log(chalk.yellowBright(`read ${imagePath} successfully!`));

      const image = await resizeImg(fs.readFileSync(imagePath), {
        width: width,
        height: height,
      });
      fs.writeFileSync(path.join(dist, imageName), image);
      console.log(chalk.greenBright(`resize ${path.join(dist, imageName)} successfully!`));
      });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

asumiendo que todo funciona, en vez de recorrer un bucle, que efectivamente lo que hace es cargarlo todo sin parar y luego va resolviendo las promesas y demas, te propongo que utilices una funcion recursivamente y se vaya llamando segun le devuelva el resultado la promesa, mas o menos de esta manera:

```js
var contador = 0; // <-- inicializamos un contador para controlar el flujo
  async function resizeImg(file){ // <-- creamos la funcion que va a ser autollamada
      const imageName = file;
      const width = customWidth;

      const imagePath = path.join(folderPath, imageName);
      const height = width * dimension(imagePath);

      console.log(chalk.yellowBright(`read ${imagePath} successfully!`));

      const image = await resizeImg(fs.readFileSync(imagePath), {
        width: width,
        height: height,
      });
      fs.writeFileSync(path.join(dist, imageName), image);
      console.log(chalk.greenBright(`resize ${path.join(dist, imageName)} successfully!`));
      
      //esta parte se añade para control de repeticiones
      
      if(contador >= files.length){ 
        console.log('proceso terminado');
      }else{
        contador++  // <-- se incrementa el contador para coger la siguiente imagen del array
        resizeImg(files[contador]) // <-- se vuelve a llamar a si misma una vez ha completado la promesa; 
      }
  };
 resizeImg(files[contador]); // <-- se inicia el proceso (contador = 0) y coge la primera imagen
```